# Raycasting for a third person shooter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to do a raycast from my player character, to the hit object of my camera raycast but I cant get my code to work, it always seems offset.

```
        void Update () {

    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray playerAim = playerCamera.GetComponent < Camera > ().ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2 ));
    Physics.Raycast(playerAim, out hit);
    Debug.DrawRay(playerAim.origin, playerAim.direction * hit.distance, Color.green);

    if (Physics.Raycast(playerAim, out hit)){
        // something was hit
        RaycastHit playerHit;
        Physics.Raycast(transform.position, hit.transform.position,  out playerHit);
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, playerHit.transform.position, Color.red);

        Debug.Log ("Distance from camera: "+ hit.distance);
        Debug.Log ("Distance from player: "+ playerHit.distance);
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzdVU.jpg

I thought `Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, playerHit.transform.position, Color.red);` should draw a red line from my player to the end of the green line the cameras hit point, instead it shoots past into the floor.

Answer (score 3):

Change Debug.DrawRay to Debug.DrawLine!

Debug.DrawRay needs a Vector3 as the origin and a Vector3 as the direction, NOT a second "target" position.

Here is my solution!

[image]

```
void FixedUpdate() {

    RaycastHit cameraHit;
    Ray cameraAim = playerCamera.GetComponent < Camera > ().ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2 ));
    Physics.Raycast(cameraAim, out cameraHit, 100f);
    Debug.DrawLine(cameraAim.origin, cameraHit.point, Color.green);
    Vector3 cameraHitPoint = cameraHit.point;
    float cameraDistance = cameraHit.distance;

    if (Physics.Raycast(cameraAim, out cameraHit)){
        // something was hit
        RaycastHit playerHit;
        Physics.Raycast(transform.position + new Vector3 (0f, 1.8f, 0f), cameraHitPoint-transform.position - new Vector3 (0f, 1.8f, 0f), out playerHit, 100f);
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position + new Vector3 (0f, 1.8f, 0f), cameraHitPoint-transform.position - new Vector3 (0f, 1.8f, 0f), Color.red);

        float playerDistance = playerHit.distance;
        Debug.Log ("Distance from player: "+ playerDistance);
        Debug.Log ("Distance from camera: "+ cameraDistance);
    }

}
```